# Need to use SQLiteOpenHelper in a Jersey REST service but I cannot pass required Android context

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey, android-sqlite

I am trying to replace in-memory data with data from a database, which will be the data that is used in a REST API.  The API is a service running on an Android box.  In order to use SQLiteOpenHelper I must pass a Context to the class that extends it.  Unfortunately, the thread that handles the REST API does not instantiate a class to which I can pass down Context, rather it configures the API as such:

```
public static void createServer(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();
            ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(ThingResource.class);
            config.register(GsonMessageBodyHandler.class);
            config.register(AndroidFriendlyFeature.class);
            JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Here's the class that requires Context for me to use:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final String DB_NAME = DatabaseContract.DATABASE_NAME;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DatabaseContract.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseContract.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //rest of class handles db methods
}
```

Here is where `createServer()` is called:

```
public class RoomStatus extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        JerseyBootstrap.createServer();
        //rest of method/class set up main screen
    }
}
```

How can I either pass Context to the REST service so I can use DbHelper or use some other method to get data from SQLite database?

Comment: Can you post the code from where you call the create server method.

Comment: The top section of code is the create server method (sorry, misread your comment.  yes, will update shortly)

Comment: edited to show server method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ThingResource is a static class, I just set the context from my main activity.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try this:

```
public static void createServer(Context context){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();
            ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(ThingResource.class);
            config.register(GsonMessageBodyHandler.class);
            config.register(AndroidFriendlyFeature.class);
            JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And call it this way:

```
public class RoomStatus extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        JerseyBootstrap.createServer(this);
        //rest of method/class set up main screen
    }
}
```